# Classifying Python array by nearest "seed" region?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, image-segmentation

I have a raster of ecological habitats which I've converted into a two-dimensional Python numpy array (example_array below). I also have an array containing "seed" regions with unique values (seed_array below) which I'd like to use to classify my habitat regions. I'd like to **'grow' my seed regions 'into' my habitat regions such that habitats are assigned the ID of the nearest seed region, as measured 'through' the habitat regions.** For example:

[image: Image of arrays]

My best approach used the `ndimage.distance_transform_edt` function to create an array depicting the nearest "seed" region to each cell in the dataset, which was then substituted back into the habitat array. This doesn't work particularly well, however, as the function doesn't measure distances "through" my habitat regions, for example below where the red circle represents an incorrectly classified cell:

[image: Incorrect output using ndimage]

Below are sample arrays for my habitat and seed data, and an example of the kind of output I'm looking for. My actual datasets are much larger - over a million habitat/seed regions. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample study area array
example_array = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                          [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                          [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                          [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
                          [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                          [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                          [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                          [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                          [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                          [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

# Plot example array
plt.imshow(example_array, cmap="spectral", interpolation='nearest')

seed_array = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                       [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0],
                       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

# Plot seeds
plt.imshow(seed_array, cmap="spectral", interpolation='nearest')

desired_output = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                           [0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3],
                           [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3],
                           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0],
                           [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3],
                           [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                           [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 3],
                           [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
                           [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
                           [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                           [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

# Plot desired output
plt.imshow(desired_output, cmap="spectral", interpolation='nearest')
```

Comment: Have you tried using an iterative approach in which you expand each seed region incrementally, moving one square "out" from the center at a time, and stop when you encounter any already-assigned cells?

Comment: I've thought about trying something similar, but I think it may be a tricky approach given my datasets are very large - over a million habitat patches/seed regions. I've updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [watershed segmentation](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_watershed.html) from scikits-image:

- Distance transform

  ```
  from scipy import ndimage as nd
  distance = nd.distance_transform_edt(example_array)
  ```
- Watershed segmentation

  ```
  from skimage.morphology import watershed, square
  result = watershed(-distance, seed_array, mask=example_array, \
                     connectivity=square(3))
  ```
- Result

  ```
  subplot(1,2,1)
  imshow(-distance, 'spectral', interpolation='none')
  subplot(1,2,2)
  imshow(result, 'spectral', interpolation='none')
  ```

[image]

---

As another variant, and following your initial approach, you can use watershed to find connected neighbours to nearest seeds. As you mentioned in the question:

- Calculate distance to the seeds:

  ```
  distance = nd.distance_transform_edt(seed_array == 0)
  ```
- Calculate watershed in the distance space:

  ```
  result = watershed(distance, seed_array, mask=example_array, \
                     connectivity=square(3))
  ```
- Plot result:

  ```
  figure(figsize=(9,3))
  subplot(1,3,1)
  imshow(distance, 'jet', interpolation='none')
  subplot(1,3,2)
  imshow(np.ma.masked_where(example_array==0, distance), 'jet', interpolation='none')
  subplot(1,3,3)
  imshow(result, 'spectral', interpolation='none')
  ```

[image]

---

**Further discussion:** Watershed method tries to grow regions from seeded peaks by *flowing* through the image gradient. As your image is binary, the regions will expand equally in all directions from the seeded points, and thus give you the point in between two regions. For more info about watershed refer to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watershed_(image_processing)).

In the first example, the distance transform is calculated in the original image, and thus the regions expand equally from seeds until they achieve the splitting point in the middle.

In the second example, the distance transform is calculated from all the pixels to any of the seeded points, and then applying watershed in that space. Watershed basically will assign each pixel to its nearest seed, but it will add a connectivity constrain.

**NOTE** the sign difference in the distance maps in both plotting and watersed.

**NOTE** In distance maps (left image in both plots), blue means close where red means far.

Comment: @Robbi Bishop-Taylor I've updated my answer many times to improve the plots. Have a look again, I think in the second plot it is your desired output.

Comment: @imaluengo Yep, I just saw the edits after I posted my comment. It now does exactly as I would expect. Thanks for the fantastic answer!

Comment: @Robbi Bishop-Taylor Glad it helped. I added an extra image to the second plot that shows the masked distance transform, to ilustrate better in which space works watershed and how it dows add a connectivity constrain (by the `mask=` parameter in the function call).